# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, typeerror

I am getting a TypeError for the property of "token" after submitting a form for an account registration (JWT authentication).
I am using React-Redux as well.

Also, is there any other way rather than storing in localStorage ?

Below are the codes for the authentication reducer and action.

authReducer.js

```
import {
    USER_LOADING,
    USER_LOADED,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    isLoading: false,
    user: null
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case USER_LOADED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false,
                user: action.payload
            };
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false
            };
        case AUTH_ERROR:
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                user: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                isLoading: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

auth.Actions

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { returnErrors } from './errorActions';
import {
    USER_LOADING,
    USER_LOADED,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL
} from './types';

//check token and load user
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    //User loading
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });

    axios
        .get('/api/auth/user', tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED,
                payload: res.data
            })
        )
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
            dispatch({
                type: AUTH_ERROR
            });
        });
};

//register user
export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => dispatch => {
    //headers
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    //request body
    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

    axios
        .post('api/users', body, config)
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        )
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL'));
            dispatch({
                type: REGISTER_FAIL
            });
        });
};

//setup config/headers and token
export const tokenConfig = getState => {
    //get token from localstorage
    const token = getState().auth.token;

    //headers
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    //if token, add to headers
    if (token) {
        config.headers['x-auth-token'] = token;
    }
    return config;
};
```

users.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

//User Model
const User = require('../../models/User');

//@route POST api/users
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    //validation
    if (!name || !email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
    }

    //check for existing users
    User.findOne({ email }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User already exists!' });
        }

        const newUser = new User({
            name,
            email,
            password
        });

        //create salt & hash
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                newUser.password = hash;
                newUser.save().then(user => {
                    jwt.sign(
                        { id: user.id },
                        config.get('jwtSecret'),
                        {
                            expiresIn: 3600
                        },
                        (err, token) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json({
                                token,
                                user: {
                                    id: user.id,
                                    name: user.name,
                                    email: user.email
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    );
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

signup.js (component)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Logo from "./assets/images/logo_transparent.png";

//import Register from "./components/Register";

//redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
//proptypes
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { register } from "./actions/authActions";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  "@global": {
    body: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white
    }
  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    color: "white"
  },
  home: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 2),
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)"
  }
}));

function SignUp(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [form, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    msg: null
  })

;

     const onChange = e => {
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      [e.target.email]: e.target.value,
      [e.target.password]: e.target.value
    });
  };

      const handleClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, email, password } = form;

        //create user object


const newUser = {
          name,
          email,
          password
        };

        //attempt to register
        props.register(newUser);
     alert("Registration details submitted (test)" + name + email + 
       password);
      };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />

      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar
          alt="logo"
          src={Logo}
          style={{
            width: 150,
            height: 150
          }}
        />
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField


autoComplete="name"
            name="name"
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="name"
            label="Full Name"
            autoFocus
            onChange={onChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            onChange={onChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
               required
               fullWidth
               name="password"
               label="Password"
               type="password"
               autoComplete="current-password"
               onChange={onChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Confirm Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} />
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>

          <Button
            href="http://localhost:3000/"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.home}
          >
            Home
          </Button>
          <br />
          <br />

          <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="http://localhost:3000/signin" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Sign in
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
        <MadeWithLove />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

SignUp.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  error: state.error //getting from reducer
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { register } //from redux actions //mapdispatchtoprop
)(SignUp); //component
```

//error screenshot

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: check the contents of your `action.payload` because the logic in the code seems to be ok

Comment: Make sure you are sending the token in the response that comes from api/users. Like @MaxSvid said, the logic seems to be ok so the problem is most likely in the payload that comes from your back end route.

Comment: @MaxSvid Thank you. However, I still could not find any fault with the code. I have edited the question and include the users.js file which the data entered from the form will be hashed and salted. How do I check the contents from the action.payload exactly? I have checked using Postman and everything seems to be working. Is the proxy settings a reason for this error too?

Comment: @FurkanO Even if I submit the form when the text field (name,email,password) is filled I got a REGISTER FAIL error and a message (Please enter all fields) which may imply that not all data from the field is sent. I have edit the question and included the signup.js component. Can you check if there's anything wrong with the code. I am still a newbie and React and need guidance. Thank you.

Comment: @FurkanO I managed to submit the data to the database with the hashed password but it still returned REGISTER_FAIL which I think the axios.post to .api/users is not working properly. So basically from @INIT-->USER_LOADING-->USER_LOADED-->REGISTER_FAIL. I have included a screenshot of the problem. Can you please check it out? Thank you.

Comment: @FurkanO I placed the console.log(action.payload) after case REGISTER_SUCESS and it logged all the data (token and user data). I still don't know why it doesn't change to REGISTER_SUCCESS because if I use Postman to get the data from /api/users with the token from the payload it returned the actual data.

Comment: @FurkanO Thanks for tips! I was so stupid. Apparently , from the action types file, I wrote export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_FAIL";  which supposed to be export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_SUCCESS";
Apparently, it was working all the time. Thank you some much for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

I see one thing which seems wrong to do it:

you are trying to post these fields `({name, email, password})` but remove the curly brace like this: `(name, email, password)`

**use this way**

```
//register user

    export const register = (name, email, password) => dispatch => {
        //headers
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
    
        //request body
        const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });
    
        axios
            .post('api/users', body, config)
            .then(res =>
                dispatch({
                    type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
            )
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL'));
                dispatch({
                    type: REGISTER_FAIL
                });
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

erase user: null from Auth Error action

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29844276)